# Linking error using TensorFlow for C on Mac: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_TF_Version", referenced from: _main in main.o

Tags: c, macos, tensorflow

I am working on Mac and I installed TensorFlow for C following this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_c

When I try to validate the installation by running the tutorial example "hello_tf.c" I get the following message error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_TF_Version", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I installed TensorFlow by looking this tutorial here https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac and the validation was successful.

How can I fix this problem? I would be also interested to know the reasons for this issue

Comment: It means the library with the TensorFlow symbols cannot be found. Check that the library is placed at `/usr/local/lib` and the at the loader searches for the tensorFlow C library in that path. See also Troubleshooting in `https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_c`

Comment: Thanks for answering. In the folder `/usr/local/lib` I found two libraries: `libtensorflow.so`  and `libtensorflow_framework.so`. In addition, I tried to indicate the path in two different ways: one as the troubleshooting section is showing and then also in xCode by adding the path in the build settings of the project. It seems that I have already set everything in the way that you suggested

Comment: Did you run `ldconfig` or are you using the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables? `libtensorflow.so` depnds on `libtensorflow_framework.so`, which you should be able to see using `otool -L /usr/local/lib/libtensorflow.so`. Hard to say for sure given the information provided so far, but if you could list out the exact sequence of steps followed, that might help track down the problem.

Comment: I am using `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. This morning I reinstalled everything using Python3.5 instead of Python3.6 and it works.